# HBASE-Passe Query to the "hbase shell" command

Tags: hbase

I would like to know if there is a way to passe a query to the hbase shell command.

In fact, I would like to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
hbase shell -q " flush ‘my_region_name’"
```

thank you!

Alina GHERMAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below and it is working:

```
echo 'list'| hbase shell
```

Basically, echo 'command' hbase shell should work.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I will try it as soon as I have my cluster available and check your answer as a correct one if it works for me as well :)